# GTM and Enhanced Ecommerce. Not showing in Analytics - Scraping DOM for DataLayer

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm having a nightmare trying to get enhanced eCommerce data showing in Google Analytics. Using Tag manager I've got the below in my data layer but I can't see anything in my Google Analytics account.

Unfortunately at the moment I'm having to scrape the DOM for the relevant information, so I'm pushing all the information to the datalayer with a 'payment ' event. The corresponding tag is correctly firing on this event.

The GTM preview inspector is showing everything as I would expect

I have ticked the relevant enabled enhanced eCommerce boxes and waited 72 hours after each attempted change but still no luck - can anyone help? I'm sure I've missed a simple step somewhere but no luck on the Google developer docs.

Many Thanks,

Eoghain

'Payment' Event:

[image: DataLayer Screen Shot]

After page Fully Loaded:

[image: DataLayer ScreenShot]

Tag:
[image: tag view]

Trigger:
[image: Trigger]

Comment: Just ruling out the obvious, make sure you aren't filtering out your own hits, check that you are sending to the correct property, also can you post screenshots of your relevant tags, variables, triggers?

Comment: Hi nyuen, thanks for your help. I've edited to add the screenshots. Yep I've worked my way through the basics, it's all pointing at the right places and other events and things are going through fine - just the eCommerce doesn't come through. There's no filtering at the moment. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah they are firing, and pushing the above into the data layer. I've picked that up through the tag manager preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I believe the issue is because you are using the Transaction type tag. This applies only to standard e-commerce. You need to piggyback your e-commerce data with either a pageview or a (non interactive) event.

Comment: Good catch ! That's definitely an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help there, I'm picking up the purchase event now so hopefully the ecommerce should start pulling through. Knew it would be something simple! Thanks again for your time, I'll let you know if it all pulls through ok in the next couple of days but looking good just now. Thanks again

Comment: All pulling through perfectly now - Thanks again for your help, Things were getting pretty desperate!!